# login require to blogging site

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using codeigniter all have been done but the problem is i want to check that user is logged in or not before submitting any blog on my site . problem is when user fill the form and then if user is not logged in he goes to home page . but i want that the user should remains on the same page . and can continue after log in . the log in form is in header view

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('user_id')) {
        redirect(base_url());
        $this->data['login'] = 'Login required to create';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` on redirect:

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('user_id')) {
    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $this->data['login'] = 'Login required to create';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('user_id')) {

    $this->session->set_flashdata('login', 'Login required to create post');
    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```